# Error trying to get the difference of two dates

Tags: php, datetime, date-difference, dateinterval

I know this question about getting the difference of two dates has been asked like **dozens of times**, but despite implementing every answer I could find, **I can't get my code to work**.

What I want to achieve is to **get the difference of two dates**, but I am getting the following error/warning:

**`Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, object given.`**

**My PHP code**:

```
<?php
    // Include the function's library
    include_once "Functions.php";

    // Set default timezone_abbreviations_list
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");

    // Establish connection to the database, pass the query and get the result
    $connection = connect("limited"); // Read-only
    $query = "SELECT `Last_Login` FROM `users`";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    // Initiate the variables
    $last_login = array();
    $now = date_create(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($last_login, date_create($data["Last_Login"]));
            /* The date in the database is saved in this format : 2016-07-10 09:43:06 */
        }
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($last_login); $i++) {
        $difference = date_diff($now, $last_login[$i], true) . "<br/>";
        echo date_format($difference, "%d");
    }
?>
```

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: `date_diff` returns an object of type `DateTimeInterval`.  You can't pass that to date_format.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php  Look at Example #1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't get the code in the question to work, so **I ended up making my own script about it**, which works perfectly.

**The PHP code**:

```
<?php
    // Establish connection to the database, pass the query and get the result
    $connection = connect("limited");
    $query = "SELECT `Last_Login` FROM `users`";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    // Initiate variables
    $now = date_parse(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $last_login = ["Last_Login" => array()];
    $difference = ["Days" => array()];
    $entries = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // For each entry in the database insert the date in its respective position in the arrays
    if ($entries) {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($last_login["Last_Login"], date_parse($data["Last_Login"]));
        }
    }

    // Calculate the difference between the present moment and the last login date
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($last_login["Last_Login"]); $i++) {
        // If the present year is bissextile convert months to seconds as 29 days each
        if ($now["year"] % 4 === 0) {
            if ($last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] === 2) {
                $present = $now["month"] * 2505600 + $now["day"] * 86400 + $now["hour"] * 3600 + $now["minute"] * 60 + $now["second"];
                $past = $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] * 2505600 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["day"] * 86400 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["hour"] * 3600 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["minute"] * 60 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["second"];
                $difference["Days"][$i] = ($present - $past) / 86400;
            }
        }
        // If the present year is not bissextile convert months to seconds as 28 days each
        else {
            if ($last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] === 2) {
                $present = $now["month"] * 2419200 + $now["day"] * 86400 + $now["hour"] * 3600 + $now["minute"] * 60 + $now["second"];
                $past = $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] * 2419200 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["day"] * 86400 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["hour"] * 3600 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["minute"] * 60 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["second"];
                $difference["Days"][$i] = ($present - $past) / 86400;
            }
        }

        // Convert months to seconds as 31 days each
        if (($last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] >= 1 && $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] <= 7 && $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] % 2 === 1) || ($last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] >= 8 && $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] <= 12 && $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] % 2 === 0)) {
            $present = $now["month"] * 2678400 + $now["day"] * 86400 + $now["hour"] * 3600 + $now["minute"] * 60 + $now["second"];
            $past = $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] * 2678400 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["day"] * 86400 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["hour"] * 3600 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["minute"] * 60 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["second"];
            $difference["Days"][$i] = ($present - $past) / 86400;
        }
        // Convert months to seconds as 30 days each
        elseif ($last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] === 4 || $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] === 6 || $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] === 9 || $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] === 11) {
            $present = $now["month"] * 2592000 + $now["day"] * 86400 + $now["hour"] * 3600 + $now["minute"] * 60 + $now["second"];
            $past = $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["month"] * 2592000 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["day"] * 86400 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["hour"] * 3600 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["minute"] * 60 + $last_login["Last_Login"][$i]["second"];
            $difference["Days"][$i] = ($present - $past) / 86400;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. Using the [\DateTime classes](http://php.net/datetime) will do all this for you with much less code. They will also take care of leap years and DST changes for you, which your code doesn't.

Comment: I want the script to **check if a user has 14 or more days to log in**. If the last time the logged in was in February of a leap year and now is March the script **will add a 29th day as well**, so you are **absolutely wrong** when you say that leap years are not accounted for. For bigger intervals, I would indeed need a more advanced code, but for my purposes something more advanced would be completely superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

`date_diff` returns a `DateInterval` object, which you can't format using `date_format`. Call `->format()` on the `$difference` instead.

Instead of `echo date_format($difference, "%d")` do a `echo $difference->format('%d')`.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar a while back, this is what I found.

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
$t = $diff->format("%a");
echo "$t";
```